# Copying data from one form to multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working on an internal webpage to help automate some email tasks. I currently have 1 form that has some generic info that will be the same in all of the following forms, and several other forms that have some customized information. My issue is I cannot get the data from the Info Form to copy to the other forms on the page. My code is below:

```
<html>
</body>
<script language="JavaScript">
function updateInput(ish){
    document.getElementById("emailsubj").value = ish;
}
</script>
<body>

Info Form
      <form id="info" name="info">
      Email Subjects:<input name="emailsubj" value="Enter Subject Here">
      </form>
<br><br>

Form 1
      <form id="form1" name="form1">
      Email<input name=emadd value="email@address.com">
      Subject<input name="subj" onblur="updateInput(this.value)">
      </form>
<br><br>

Form 2     
      <form id="form2" name="form2">
      Email<input name=emadd value="email@address.com">
      Subject<input name="subj" onblur="updateInput(this.value)">
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

All of the non-information forms will have a submit button on them to do the appropriate function. I'm not opposed to using onchange rather than onblur, however testing that didn't help me any in my tests. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think its backwards. You are asking the form1 and form2 subj inputs to update the info input in your code. But you question seems to be asking the reverse?

Comment: yes your right, i was thinking my code was backwards but i wasnt sure, i'm looking at your code now

Comment: I just added a no-jquery answer and codepen :)

Comment: also you should replace `value="Enter Subject Here"` with `placeholder="Enter Subject Here"`

Comment: Worked awesome! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery Answer**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKIgc

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Info Form
        <form id="info" name="info">
            Email Subjects:<input name="emailsubj" placeholder="Enter Subject Here">
        </form>

        Form 1
        <form id="form1" name="form1">
            Email<input name="emadd" placeholder="email@address.com">
            Subject<input name="subj">
        </form>

        Form 2
        <form id="form2" name="form2">
            Email<input name="emadd" placeholder="email@address.com">
            Subject<input name="subj">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('input[name=emailsubj]').on("keyup",function(e){
  $('[name=subj]').val($(this).val())
});
```

**No jQuery Answer**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzKxG

```
<html><body>

Info Form
<form id="info" name="info">
    Email Subjects:<input name="emailsubj" value="Enter Subject Here" onblur="updateInput(this.value)">
</form>
<br/><br/>

Form 1
<form id="form1" name="form1">
    Email<input name="emadd" value="email@address.com">
    Subject<input name="subj">
</form>
<br/><br/>

Form 2     
<form id="form2" name="form2">
    Email<input name="emadd" value="email@address.com">
    Subject<input name="subj">
</form>
</body></html>
```

JS

```
function updateInput(ish){
    var a = document.getElementsByName("subj");
    for(var i in a){
        a[i].value = ish;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm fine by using jQuery, but i've never used it before. How do i link it into my code?

Comment: I added jquery and lodash ;) two libraries I don't like to be without